# Where is the difference in meaning here?

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-tense

Difference in meaning between:

1. I haven’t eaten anything all day.
2. I have not been eating all day.

thank you very much :)

Comment: The second is how you'd reply to your spouse if said person said "All you've done all day is eat, eat, eat."

Answer (score 2):

The first means the speaker has gone the whole day without eating any food. The second *could* mean that as well, but more likely means that the speaker has spent *some* part of the day eating, but not *all* of it.

Consider these possible contexts:

1. "Do you want to grab some food?" "Yes! I haven't eaten anything all day!"
2. "I can't believe you spent the entire day stuffing your face!" "I have not been eating all day!"

Comment: I agree +1 and the final sentence would probably be said emphatically as, "I have **not** been eating all day!"  The argument might continue, "You **have** been eating all day.", "No I have **not**" etc.!